# RubyMine: key press to "convert to single quoted"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, quotes, rubymine, double-quotes, single-quotes

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle between single quotes and double quotes in a Ruby code? Or a key I can set up to accept the Inspection Hint?

Thanks, M.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To accept any inspection hint in RubyMine, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then use the arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the quickfix to apply.

Answer (score 9):

Current as of RubyMine 2016.2, there is an easier way to convert all quotes via the keyboard:

- select part of string whose quotation type you want to change
- Alt + Enter to accept inspection hint
- Arrow right
- "Fix all 'Double quoted string' problems in file"

[image: Fix all option in RubyMine]

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have a double quoted string as `"some_string"` then you need to select all **"some_string"** including both the quotes and press quote key to get `'some_string'` i.e single quoted string. To get the double quotes `'some_string' => "some_string"` follow the same process and press shift+quote key. Hope your problem is solved @Martin.

Comment: @MartinCleaver both of these answers seem acceptable for your question, but I would vote for this one in conjunction with using ctrl+w until the entire string with quotes is selected because it's quicker for me. Just wondering why one hasn't been accepted?